# Using split after a set statement in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of words (equivalent to about two full sentences) and I want to split it into two parts: one part containing 90% of the words and another part containing 10% of them. After that, I want to print a list of the unique words within the 10% list, lexicographically sorted. This is what I have so far:

```
    pos_90 = (90*len(words)) // 100 #list with 90% of the words
    pos_90 = pos_90 + 1 #I incremented the number by 1 in order to use it as an index
    pos_10 = (10*len(words)) // 100 #list with 10% of the words
    list_90 = words[:pos_90] #Creation of the 90% list
    list_10 = words[pos_10:] #Creation of the 10% list
    uniq_10 = set(list_10) #List of unique words out of the 10% list
    split_10 = uniq_10.split()
    sorted_10 = split_10.sort()
    print(sorted_10)
```

I get an error saying that `split` cannot be applied to `set`, so I assume my mistake must be in the last lines of code. Any idea about what I'm missing here?

Comment: What do you expect `uniq_10.split()` to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457793/sorting-a-set-of-values)

Comment: I was thinking of separating all the words to have them sorted later, though I understand it might be redundant. In any case, the error I get doesn't have to do with that, I think

Comment: `uniq_10` is already a set, `split` is a function you apply on string in order to make them list.

Comment: Note: As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53071119/364696), ignoring your actual exception, your code has a logic error. `pos_10` is an index ~10% of the way into `words`, so `words[pos_10:]` says "give me everything from 10% in through the end", which is ~90% of all the words (the last 90%). So `list_90` ends up being the first ~90% of words, and `list_10` ends up as the last ~90% of words. At no point do you take 10% of the words.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I used `list_10 = words[pos_90:]` instead, but I'm still getting more unique words than what I was expecting. Is this last statement wrong or is the way I selected unique words wrong?

Comment: @MeAll: Without the input, expected output, and actual output part of a [MCVE], I can't answer that. Providing a real [MCVE] serves multiple purposes; minimizing the example often means you identify the problem (and don't have to ask at all), and providing a complete, reproducible error with inputs/outputs is the only way we can help. We can't psychically debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` only makes sense when converting from one long `str` to a `list` of the components of said `str`. If the input was in the form `'word1 word2 word3'`, yes, `split` would convert that `str` to `['word1', 'word2', 'word3']`, but your input is a `set`, and there is no sane way to "split" a `set` like you seem to want; it's already a bag of separated items.

All you really need to do is convert your `set` back to a sorted `list`. Replace:

```
split_10 = uniq_10.split()
sorted_10 = split_10.sort()
```

with either:

```
sorted_10 = list(uniq_10)
sorted_10.sort()  # NEVER assign the result of .sort(); it's always going to be None
```

or the simpler one-liner that encompasses both listifying and sorting:

```
sorted_10 = sorted(uniq_10)  # sorted, unlike list.sort, returns a new list
```

The final option is generally the most Pythonic approach to converting an arbitrary iterable to `list` and sorting that new `list`, returning the result. It doesn't mutate the input, doesn't rely on the input being a specific type (`set`, `tuple`, `list`, it doesn't matter), and it's simpler to boot. You only use `list.sort()` when you already have a known `list`, and don't mind mutating it.

Comment: @Austin: It's not a dupe though, given that the OP is asking *why* their code doesn't work, not merely "How do I do this?" It's a relevant link, but not a dupe.

Comment: @ShadowRanger this works, though I'm getting more words than just the unique words. Should I modify anything else?

Comment: @MeAll: Did you see [my note about the logic error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070941/using-split-after-a-set-statement-in-python/53071030?noredirect=1#comment93040784_53070941)? `list_10` should be initialized with either `words[:pos_10]` or `words[pos_90:]` (depending on whether it should overlap the contents of `list_90` or not).