# Python sort list to set

Tags: python, python-3.x

*edit

I make

```
word=['I','love','hello','world','love','I']
```

when I convert to set, It change the order to

```
print(set(word))
output: {'world', 'I', 'hello', 'love'}
```

How to sort the set again to be

```
{'I', 'love', 'hello', 'world'}
```

Comment: Sets are unordered. If you want order, convert back to a list. E.g. `print(sorted(set(word)))`

Comment: If you want an "ordered set", you could also use a `dict` in Python 3 and ignore the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457793/sorting-a-set-of-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sets are unordered. If you want order, convert back to a list.

E.g.

```
print(sorted(set(word)))
```

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) will sort your items and return a list.

However, if you want to **retain the order** of your elements rather than sort them, you can use a set for deduplication and a list for ordering, something like this:

```
def unique(items):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for item in items:
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)
            result.append(item)
    return result
```

and use it as:

```
>>> word = ['I','love','hello','world','love','I']
>>> print(unique(word))
['I', 'love', 'hello', 'world']
```

Comment: ... provided that OP wants the items in sorted order and not in their original order.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want an ordered collection of unique values, you can create a `dict` from the list, either with a dict comprehension or `dict.fromkeys`. In Python 3, dictionaries will retain insertion order; for older versions, use `collections.OrderedDict`. The dict will have values besides the keys, but you can just ignore those.

```
>>> word = ['a','b','c','c','b','e']
>>> {k: None for k in word}
{'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'e': None}
>>> dict.fromkeys(word)
{'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'e': None}
```

Other than `sorted`, this also works if the original order is different than the sorted order.

```
>>> word = ['f','a','b','c','c','b','e']
>>> dict.fromkeys(word)
{'f': None, 'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'e': None}
```

You can then either convert the result to `list` or keep it a `dict` and add more values, but if you make it a `set`, the order will be lost again. Like a `set`, the `dict` also allows fast O(1) lookup, but no set operations like intersection or union.