# How to use sort() for set() values in Python?

Tags: python

**Basic code:**

```
var1 = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
var2 = ['c', 'a']

print(set(var1).difference(set(var2)))
```

**Output:**

```
{'b', 'd'}
```

**Question**

Is it possible to sort this output into alphabetical order? If so, how can I?

**This is what I have tried:**

```
print(set(var1).difference(set(var2)).sort())
```

**But error shows up:**

```
    print(set(var1).difference(set(var2)).sort())
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: That's not a dictionary, it's a set. You can used `sorted(set(var1).difference(var2))` to turn the set into a sorted list, but you cannot sort the set itself (sets are, by definition, unordered).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457793/sorting-a-set-of-values)

Comment: Also, `set(...).difference` can take an arbitrary iterable as its argument; you don't need to wrap `var2` in a set first.

Comment: Your question is about sorting a set. How you created the set does not really matter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sets have no order, so sorting them makes no sense. But if you pass a set to `sorted` it will be turned into a list and sorted:

```
print(sorted(set(var1).difference(set(var2))))
```

Comment: that gives me output of `None`.

Comment: sorry, forgot that `sort()` doesn't return the sorted list. Use `sorted` instead, as the edited answer indicates.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code that will solve the problem:

```
var1 = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
var2 = ['c', 'a']

print(sorted(set((set(var1).difference(set(var2))))))
```

Output:

```
['b', 'd']
```

You might be wondering that the output is a list and not a set.  That's because the whole point of using a set, both in mathematics as a tool and in programming languages as a data structure is that it's not ordered. Meaning the sets {p, q} and {q, p} are the same set!

Comment: The return value of `set.difference` is already a set, so you don't have to call `set()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of elements in your set sorted alphabetically by comparing the `ord` of the different characters.

```
test_list = ["a", "b", "u", "x", "e", "f", "k", "z"]
test_set = set(test_list)
sorted_list = sorted(test_set, key=ord) # == ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'u', 'x', 'z']
```

Comment: `key=ord` doesn't do anything particularly useful. Strings are already sorted lexicographically by default.

Comment: Maybe, but it implies that `key` could be something else, so maybe someone deeps further in that topic if they are interested.

Comment: The fact that a keyword argument `key` exists is hardly a reason to use it unnecessarily.