# Pyspark convert columns into array of structs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following schema:

```
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_agent_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_0_epochTs_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_0_name_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_0_timestamp_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_1_epochTs_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_1_name_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_1_timestamp_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_1_value_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_2_epochTs_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_2_name_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_2_timestamp_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_2_value_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
```

And I need to add a column with the tags as an array of structs like this:

```
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_agent_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_0_epochTs_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_0_name_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_0_timestamp_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_1_epochTs_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_1_name_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_1_timestamp_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_1_value_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_2_epochTs_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_2_name_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_2_timestamp_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags_2_value_DEVICE_METADATA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- device_metadata_tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- epochTs: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: double (nullable = true)
```

But as you can see in the tags I don't always have all of the columns I need for example I don't have `tags_0_value_DEVICE_METADATA` and I don't know how long the list of the tags is, here its 3 but it can change.
Is there a way to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [columns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.columns.html) to get all column names and then use the column names to reorder the data:

#### 1. Get the column names and extract the tags and the suffixes

```python
df = ...
cols=df.select("data.*").columns
cols.remove("user_agent_DEVICE_METADATA")

import re
tag=set(map(lambda s: re.search('(tags_.*?)_',s).group(1),cols))
suffix=set(map(lambda s: re.search('(tags_.*?)_(.*)',s).group(2),cols))
```

The order of the elements of the struct and the order of the elements within the array are not fixed. If the orders matter `tag` and `suffix` can be [sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17458090/2129801).

#### 2. Calculate the column object for the structs

For each tag a struct is constructed. Each struct consists of all possible suffixes. If a tag/suffix combination does not exist in the original dataframe, it is filled with `null`.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def getStructElements(t):
      for s in suffix:
            col = t + "_" + s
            name = re.search('(.*?)_',s).group(1)
            if col in cols:
                  yield(F.col("data." + col).alias(name))
            else:
                  yield(F.lit(None).alias(name))

def createStructs():
      for t in tag:
            s = list(getStructElements(t))
            yield F.struct(s)
```

#### 3. Select the data in the required format

```python
df.select(F.col("data"), F.array(list(createStructs())).alias("device_metadata_tags"))
```

Comment: You should add sorted to tags like `tag=sorted(set(map(lambda s: re.search('(tags_.*?)_',s).group(1),cols)))` what you wrote sometime returned the wrong order for me and then the array did not match the original columns

Answer (score 1):

If your data columns are well structured (naming is always `tags_x_y_DEVICE_METADATA`) and your output is fixed to `name, value, epochTs, timestamp`.

You can try this approach.

First, collect `tags_x_` into a struct and fill any missing columns.

```
output_cols = ['name', 'value', 'epochTs', 'timestamp']

# For tags_0_***
F.struct(*[F.col(f'data.tags_0_{c}_DEVICE_METADATA').alias(c) 
           if f'tags_0_{c}_DEVICE_METADATA' in df.select('data.*').columns
           else F.lit(None).alias(c)                              
           for c in output_cols])
```

Loop this operation for `tags_0/1/2`. Then, collect all `struct` into an array.

Final code.

```
df = (df.select('data', *[F.struct(*[F.col(f'data.tags_{num}_{c}_DEVICE_METADATA').alias(c) 
                                     if f'tags_{num}_{c}_DEVICE_METADATA' in df.select('data.*').columns
                                     else F.lit(None).alias(c)                              
                                     for c in output_cols]
                                  ).alias(f'tags_{num}')
                          for num in range(3)])
      .select('data', F.array(*[F.col(f'tags_{num}') for num in range(3)]).alias('device_metadata_tags')))
```

Comment: I wish I could accept your answer as well! this worked for me without changing anything, I just chose the first answer because I like generators